# How to set default value to selected in material-UI multi select box in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using [Multi Select box](https://v4.mui.com/components/selects/#multiple-select) from material-ui v4.

I set a default value in the useState and I can see the values but when I open the select the default list is not selected and when I click on it, it added again to the select box so I have the same value multiple time.

```
    /* 
    the full list configurationList [{_id: '21375d87eed65e103c790121', configurationName: 'Regime1'},{_id: '21375d87eed65e103c790122', configurationName: 'Regime2'},
    {_id: '21375d87eed65e103c790123', configurationName: 'Regime3'}]
    
The currentHistogramConfigurationList [{_id: '21375d87eed65e103c790121', configurationName: 'Regime1'}]*/

            const [
            histogrammeConfigurations,
            setHistogrammeConfigurations
          ] = useStateWithDep(
            currentHistogramConfigurationList ? currentHistogramConfigurationList : []
          );
        
          const handleChange = (event) => {
            console.log('*handle_Change', event.target.value);
            setHistogrammeConfigurations(event.target.value);
          };
        
          const handleDelete = (_id) => () => {
            console.log('*handle_Delete', _id);
            const chipDataConst = [...histogrammeConfigurations];
            const chipToDelete = chipDataConst.map(({ _id }) => _id).indexOf(_id);
            console.log('*handle_chipToDelete', chipToDelete);
            chipDataConst.splice(chipToDelete, 1);
            setHistogrammeConfigurations(chipDataConst);
          };
        //...
        <Select 
            labelId='demo-mutiple-chip-label'
            id='demo-mutiple-chip'
            multiple
            value={histogrammeConfigurations}
            onChange={handleChange}
            input={<Input id='select-multiple-chip' />}
            renderValue={(selected) => (
            <div className={classes.chips}>
               {selected.map((value) => {
                        return (
                          <Chip
                            key={value._id}
                            label={value.configurationName}
                            className={classes.chip}
                            onDelete={handleDelete(value._id)}
                          />
                        );
                      })}
                    </div>
                  )}
                  MenuProps={MenuProps}
                >
                  {configurationList.map((item) => (
                    <MenuItem
                      key={item._id}
                      value={item}
                      style={getStyles(item._id, histogrammeConfigurations, theme)}
                      // selected
                    >
                      {item.configurationName}
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
                </Select>
```

Comment: You must use `value`. When you only use `Select`, without `MenuItem` and `Input`, does it's work? I think you have to set a `series of values` on the `Input`

Comment: @AliYaghoby without the MenuItem I can not see the values and how to set the values on the `<Input/>`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to handle the input like this

```js
const [histogrammeConfigurations, setHistogrammeConfigurations ] = useStateWithDep(currentHistogramConfigurationList ? currentHistogramConfigurationList : []);

<Select
    value={histogrammeConfigurations}
    input={
        <Input
            id='select-multiple-chip'
            value={histogrammeConfigurations}
        />
    }
>
    ...
</Select>
```

Comment: I'did not work. when I open the Select component the default values is not selected.

Comment: Handle `onChange` and another `props`, I only sent the necessary `porps`. Set the rest of the values yourself

Comment: I alrady found the problem the `useState([{...},{...}])`  i figured it out when I tired a simple array of strings and an array of object. 
the array of object don't work properly.
this is a link to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69669285/how-to-set-list-of-object-as-default-values-in-material-ui-multi-select-box-in-r/69669334#69669334