# How to set list of object as default values in material-UI multi select box in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cbo5eg?file=demo.js) using [multi select box](https://v4.mui.com/components/selects/#multiple-select) from material-ui v4.

The example contains two components the first with a default value list of object that is not working properly and a second component with a list of string that works fine.

The problem:  (first component) when I open the Select component the default values is not selected and when I click on the default value it added again to the select box I have the same value multiple time.

Comment: The code works in your stackbliz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i tried Array.reduce (Shallow copy):

```
  const namesCopy = names.reduce((newArray, element) => {
    props.defaultList.map((item) => {
      if (item._id === element._id) {
        newArray.push(element);
      }
    });
    return newArray;
  }, []);
  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState(namesCopy);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the same object, eg change.

```
const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([
    { _id: '1', name: 'Oliver Hansen' },
    { _id: '2', name: 'Van Henry' },
  ]);
```

to:

```
const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState(names.slice(0,2));
```

I don't remember this being necessary previously with materialUI, but it fixes the problem in your demo, so maybe I just haven't run into it before.

Comment: names.slice(0, 2) worked but it's not  a solution the default values can be any values ​​of the total list  I can't use slice(0,2) every time.